# Using EXTI line for software event

Tags: embedded, stm32f4

I'm using STM32F4 and I want to generate a pulse. the question is how do I know the pulse is generated by set certain bit of swier in exti or not? is there any way to detect the generated pulse, or any alternative way to indicate that? how should I do to achieve that way with std library?

[image]

any code to config exti for soft event mode, and how to detect or indicate generated pulse

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. Then come back and [edit] your question, telling us what you want to do with the pulse. Commonly you can detect the effect of the pulse, like measure it on an output pin with an oscilloscope.

Comment: It's really not clear what you're trying to do here, but if you really want to _generate_ a pulse, this would typically be done using one of the STM32's timers, or even just a regular GPIO pin, if the timing requirements were not too strict.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.  EXTI is an _input_, "pulse generation" suggests an output. Looks like an X-Y problem.

Answer (score 0):

The "pulse generator" in the diagram is merely a description of how the event generation hardware works.  It is not a user accessible function.

The difference between an interrupt and an event is not clear in ST's manuals, but an interrupt signals the NVIC, and will result in the associated handler code being executed, while an *event* is used to directly signal a peripheral device.

So here if the configured EXTI edge occurs, and the corresponding event mask bit is set, a pulse is generated signalling some other *internal* on-chip peripheral.

> there any way to detect the generated pulse

Not in the context of that diagram.  It is probably irrelevant to whatever it is you are trying to do.

> how should I do to achieve that way with std library?

Classic X-Y problem, you have fixated a solution and are asking questions about the solution.   You need to ask about the problem.  Unfortunately it is entirely unclear what that problem is.

Moreover what "*std library*"? Are you using the older "standard peripheral library" or the abysmal CubeMX library?

If you want to simply generate an output pulse in response to an edge in an input, then most of the timer peripherals support that with zero software overhead.  Search your parts reference manual for *"One-pulse mode"* in relation to any of the available timer peripherals.